# Query in Kibana doesn't return logs with Regexp

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

I have a field named `log.file.path` in Elasticsearch and it has `/var/log/dev-collateral/uaa.2020-09-26.log` value, I tried to retrieve all logs that `log.file.path` field starts with `/var/log/dev-collateral/uaa`
I used the below regexp but it doesn't work.

```
{
    "regexp":{
        "log.file.path": "/var/log/dev-collateral/uaa.*"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see why it is not working? I've indexed two documents using Kibana UI like below -

```
PUT myindex/_doc/1
{
  "log.file.path" : "/var/log/dev-collateral/uaa.2020-09-26.log"
}

PUT myindex/_doc/2
{
  "log.file.path" : "/var/log/dev-collateral/uaa.2020-09-26.txt"
}
```

When I try to see the **tokens** for of the text on `log.file.path` field using `_analyze` API

```
POST _analyze
{
  "text": "/var/log/dev-collateral/uaa.2020-09-26.log"
}
```

It gives me,

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "var",
      "start_offset" : 1,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "log",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "dev",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "collateral",
      "start_offset" : 13,
      "end_offset" : 23,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "uaa",
      "start_offset" : 24,
      "end_offset" : 27,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "2020",
      "start_offset" : 28,
      "end_offset" : 32,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 5
    },
    {
      "token" : "09",
      "start_offset" : 33,
      "end_offset" : 35,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 6
    },
    {
      "token" : "26",
      "start_offset" : 36,
      "end_offset" : 38,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 7
    },
    {
      "token" : "log",
      "start_offset" : 39,
      "end_offset" : 42,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 8
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see, Elasticsearch has split your input text into tokens when you insert them on your index. This is because elasticsearch uses **standard analyzer** when we index documents and **it splits our document to small parts as a token, remove punctuations, lowercased text etc**. That's whey your current regexp query doesn't work.

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "log.file.path": "var"
    }
  }
}
```

If you try this way it will work but for your case, you need to match every **log.file.path** that ends with **.log** So what do now? Just don't apply analyzers while indexing documents. The keyword type stores the string you provide as it is.

**Create mapping with `keyword` type,**

```
PUT myindex2/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "log.file.path": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index documents,**

```
PUT myindex2/_doc/1
{
  "log.file.path" : "/var/log/dev-collateral/uaa.2020-09-26.log"
}

PUT myindex2/_doc/2
{
  "log.file.path" : "/var/log/dev-collateral/uaa.2020-09-26.txt"
}
```

**Search with `regexp`**,

```
GET myindex2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "log.file.path": "/var/log/dev-collateral/uaa.2020-09-26.*"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this query and it works!

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "log.file.path.keyword": {
        "value": "/var/log/dev-collateral/uaa.*",
        "flags": "ALL",
        "max_determinized_states": 10000,
        "rewrite": "constant_score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```